# How to give proper permission for file system in containers running on OCP?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, openshift

I have my docker application running on OpenShift. I am facing a permission issue in the container. My docker file looks like this:

```
.....

RUN chmod +x /tmp/ui-app/isf-management-api

RUN chgrp -R 0 /tmp/ui-app/build/ && \
    chmod -R g=u /tmp/ui-app/build/

# Set the entry point
ENTRYPOINT (cd /tmp/ui-app && ./management-api)

USER 65534

EXPOSE 10555
```

I added chgrp and chmod so that I could create/update the file in the container programmatically. It works correctly on some clusters but some clusters still give the permission issue. After debugging more I found the user on containers are different.

In non-working case :

```
sh-4.4$ touch 1
touch: cannot touch '1': Permission denied
sh-4.4$ whoami
nobody
sh-4.4$
```

on the other hand, in the working case it is :

```
sh-4.4$ whoami
1000630000
sh-4.4$ touch 3
sh-4.4$
```

But the docker image is the same in both places.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: It looks like OpenShift is assigning you a different user ID when it runs the container; that means you're not going to be able to set a fixed user ID in the image.  How are you actually running the container; do you have a Kubernetes manifest or other deployment details?

Comment: It's an operator deployment.  My application gets deployed when CRDs/CRs are getting created.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [the docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.9/openshift_images/create-images.html#images-create-guide-openshift_create-images):

> By default, OpenShift Container Platform runs containers using an arbitrarily assigned user ID. This provides additional security against processes escaping the container due to a container engine vulnerability and thereby achieving escalated permissions on the host node.

> For an image to support running as an arbitrary user, directories and files that are written to by processes in the image must be owned by the root group and be read/writable by that group. Files to be executed must also have group execute permissions.

The docs then give some example of how to build a Dockerfile that complies with this, as well as how to modify the SecurityContextConstraint if you really must violate this security policy. (Which it doesn't sound like you need to.)

Comment: I already have added chgrp/chmod in DockerFile, it works on some clusters but not on all. Not sure what is the issue. Config on clusters are not identical it seems.

Comment: Maybe I leapt to a conclusion. But why are you using a USER command? Especially after ENTRYPOINT. I still think the root cause of your problem is related to arbitrary users somehow. Especially since on some clusters you are getting your requested nobody user. And on others you are getting an arbitrary uid. Maybe a SCCs? Versions of base image?

Comment: I have used the USER command to run containers with non-root. The same base image is used in both cases. In fact, the same DockerFile is used while building the image.

Comment: I meant a USER command _there_. USER only affects things (including ENTRYPOINT) that follow it.

Comment: I got the issue. USER is only the issue. I should be using 1001 instead of 65534

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue. USER 65534 is nobody. DockerFile should contain 1001 as non-root user.